# Check if point x is in a sphere

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

Is this the right formula to check if a point is inside a sphere:

```
var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY, z = 120;
var r = 100, x2 = 100, y2 = 100, z2 = 100;

var dx = x - x2;
var dy = y - y2;
var dz = z - z2;
dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
console.log(dx, dy, dz, dist);


if (dist < r) {
    console.log("oi");
}
```

I use a function that gets called on mouse click. On my document there is an image which I use to check if I'm clicking inside of it. The image locations are the `x2`, `y2` and `y2` coordinates.

The location of the click is `mouseX` and `mouseY` and a fixed depth because I'm not able to test depth when clicking a 2d object.

Comment: I don't think it will work. You are not paying attention to the fact, that objects that are farther away appear to be smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that *X2 = (x2, y2, z2)* is the center of your sphere and *X = (x, y, z)* is the point you are interested in then yes you have the good formula to check if your point is **strictly** inside the sphere: **dist(X, X2) < r**.

Note that if you want to be able to click on the surface of the sphere, your test become `if (dist <= r)`.

Comment: Oke thanks for the answer. Confirmation is sometimes all you need.

Comment: or `abs(dist - r) < epsilon`

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah - You are totally right but I don't think adding a parameter epsilon is very useful in this case.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah - After reflexion, I don't think your answer is good ^^ If the distance is too great then (dist - r) is negative so the test is (dist - r < 0) for a point inside the sphere. If you take the absolute value, then you are testing how close the point is to the surface.

Comment: @Philou what if you were inside the sphere

Comment: Let's say r=10 and your point is at a distance dist=6 from the center of the sphere then dist-r=-4 < 0. However, abs(dist-r)=4 > epsilon and the test gives a false negative